# Error message caused by slide_index_dbl (::slider) embedded in mutate function (::dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, slider, mutate

I have this dataframe with columns 'Person', 'NoShow', and 'date'.:

```
df <- data.frame(Person = c('334','334','334','334','334','334','334','334','334'), 
                 NoShow = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0), 
                 date = c('2014-01-01','2016-06-01','2017-01-01','2018-05-01','2021-01-01','2021-06-03','2022-04-14','2022-04-14','2023-05-03')
)
```

To create a variable that counts the number of future no-shows within two years of the current date, I run this code:

```
library(lubridate); library(dplyr); library(slider)
df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  arrange(Person, date) %>% # slider unfortunately requires dates be sorted
  mutate(no_shows_next2yr = slide_index_dbl(
    NoShow, date, sum, .before = days(-1), .after = years(2)
  ))
```

This works fine in this fake dataset. When I try to apply the exact same code on my real data (with exactly the same variables), I get this error message:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `no_shows_next2yr = slider::slide_index_dbl(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 2326: Person = "456".
Caused by error in `slider::slide_index_dbl()`:
ℹ In locations: 5
! Endpoints generated by `.after` must be in ascending order.
```

I inspected the Person ID (456) in the error message but I cannot figure out why this is not working. Both variables 'Person' and 'date' are in ascending order.

Comment: If you assign `df_test <- df %>% mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% group_by(Person) %>% arrange(Person, date)`, what does `slide_index_dbl(df_test$NoShow, df_test$date, sum, .before = days(-1), .after = years(2))` return, especially for your ID 456?

Comment: Deleted my original answer because I messed up. That code returns a dataframe where the dates are in ascending order for each Person.

Comment: It returns a data.frame? Perhaps this is the problem. On your example, it returns a vector. I guess the example and your actual data differ.

Comment: I created a new dataframe by adding "df <- " at the beginning. But even when I don't do that I get the same error message.

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: I'm about to post a new question where I provide the code to create the dataframe and the code I run that creates the error message. There's something different between the dataframe I used here and the dataframe I actually work in, otherwise it wouldn't work on one df but not the other... but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: As noted in separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76024180/count-future-and-past-events-with-a-time-cut-off the issue with the OP's data had to do with leap days. For instance, there are multiple possible days that are "two years after 2020-02-29". This can be fixed by updating the code to use, for instance, `.after =  ~.x %m+% months(24)`