# Count past events with a cutoff

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with columns 'Person', 'NoShow', and 'date'.

Code to create the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Person = c('334','334','334','334','334','334','334','334','334'), 
                 NoShow = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0), 
                 date = c('2014-01-01','2016-06-01','2017-01-01','2018-05-01','2021-01-01','2021-06-03','2022-04-14','2022-04-14','2023-05-03'),
                 date_num = c(20140101, 20160601, 20170101, 20180501, 20210101, 20210603,20220414,20220414,20230503)
)
```

I want to create a new variable that counts the number of previous no-shows within two years of the current date.

Comment: Have you tried answers to your prior question but with the .before and .after terms adjusted?

Comment: I did, but or some reason get the an error message when I run the code on my actual dataset - see my QU here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76023012/error-message-caused-by-slide-index-dbl-slider-embedded-in-mutate-function?noredirect=1#comment134079691_76023012. And since this code works only for ascending dates anyways, I posed the question here, since here I want to look back in time rather than ahead.

Comment: I'd try replacing `.before = days(-1), .after = years(2)` which looks from one day forward to 2 years forward to `.before = years(2), .after = days(-1)`, which looks from two years prior to one day prior.  (In that syntax, negative one day "after" is equal to one day before.)

Comment: Got it. The issue is that I can't run the code for future no-shows without getting the error message: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `nextnoshow_f_2y = slider::slide_index_dbl(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 2553: Person = "456".
Caused by error in `slider::slide_index_dbl()`:
ℹ In locations: 7
! Endpoints generated by `.after` must be in ascending order.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.